Existence of solutions to a linear minimization problem on a sequentially weak* compact unit ball
I consider function spaces on the interval $(0,T)$. Let $\varphi \in L^2(0,T)$ such that $(\varphi,\ell)_{L^2} = 0$ for all $\ell \in L$, where $L$ is the subspace of affine functions, i.e. $\ell(x)=ax+b$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. Now I define a linear functional $\Psi:BV(0,T)/L \to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$\Psi(u+L) = (\varphi,u)_{L^2}.$$
$\Psi$ is well defined by the assumption of $\varphi$ and the compact embedding $BV(0,T) \hookrightarrow_c L^2(0,T)$ and moreover bounded. I also have already shown, that the unit ball $B$ in $BV(0,T)/L$ is weak* compact by identifying the predual of $BV(0,T)/L$ as a separable Banach space. $B$ is metrizable and therefore sequentially weak* compact.
How can I show the existence of a solution to the minimization problem
$$ \min_{u+L\in B} \Psi(u+L).$$
My approach is to follow the direct method:

Let $\{u_k+L\}\subset B$ denote an infimizing sequence, i.e. $$\Psi(u_k+L)\to \inf_{u+L\in B}\Psi(u+L) \quad \text{for } k\to \infty.$$
By sequentially weak* compactness, I can choose a weak* convergent subsequence (relabled by $k$), $$u_k+L \rightharpoonup^* \bar{u}+L$$ for a $\bar{u}+L\in BV(0,T)/L$.

Now I am stuck on how I can conclude something like $\lim \Psi(u_k+L) = \Psi(\bar{u}+L)$ or at least $\liminf \Psi(u_k+L) = \Psi(\bar{u}+L)$. I would intuitively think its connected to the Hahn-Banach theorem or the compact embedding $BV(0,T) \hookrightarrow_c L^2(0,T)$.
The first idea that I had is, denoting by $X$ the predual of $BV(0,T)/L$, that $\Psi \in X^{**}$. With the canonical isometric embedding map it holds $X\subset X^{**}$. So if I can find a representative $x_0\in X$ such that $$\Psi (u+L) = \langle u+L, x_0\rangle \quad \text{for all } u+L \in X^*,$$
I can conclude by the weak* convergence
$$ \Psi(u_k+L) = \langle u_k+L, x_0 \rangle \to \langle \bar{u}+L, x_0 \rangle = \Psi(\bar{u}+L).$$
But the existence of such a $x_0$ is not obvious by the non-reflexivity.
My second approach is, that $\{u_k+L\}$ is bounded in $BV(0,T)/L$, so we can find a bounded sequence of representatives $\tilde{u}_k \in u_k+L$. By the compact embedding, there exists an $L^2$ convergent subsequence (relabled with $k$) $\tilde{u}_k \to \tilde{u} \in L^2(0,T)$. In particular
$$(\varphi, u_k)_{L^2} \to (\varphi, \tilde{u})_{L^2}.$$
But it is still left to show $\bar{u} = \tilde{u}$.
The problem can be found in the proof of Theorem 2 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2112.06846 by J.Iglesias and D.Walter. Many thanks in advance!
